# Symfony2 - process launching a symfony2 command

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous, process, symfony-process

My goal is to launch some time consuming functions in the background to avoid user to wait before the server response is rendered.

I have a Symfony project where I am launching an asynchronous process from a controller. This process will launch a Symfony command that will call another controller.

The problem is when I am calling the process with `start()`

```
$process = new Process('/usr/bin/php '.$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/console scopusftpupload ' . escapeshellcmd($params));
$process->start();
```

Then nothing happens with the process, but the redirect and some other code that I have later works.

However, if I do

```
$process->run();
```

Then the process works fine, but I need to wait until the proceess finished in order to render the view.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround to this problem using exec instaed of creating a new Process object.

```
exec('/usr/bin/php '.$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/console scopusftpupload ' . escapeshellcmd($params) . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Answer (score 0):

We do our asynchronous processing with Gearman job server - http://gearman.org/

There are bundles that streamlines the use of Gearman in a Symfony project. We use mmoreram/GearmanBundle - https://github.com/mmoreram/GearmanBundle. Basically, you create your worker, which can be a service, and call it for time consuming tasks. We use it for data imports that take long time.

Comment: Thank you @dmnptr, this may work but is a bit complicated for the usage I need. I found a workaround using exec, will post the answer

Comment: However, this deserves a +1 :)